# Use Ubuntu as bluetooth speaker

Tags: sound, bluetooth, ubuntu-mate

I have a raspberry running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 connected to speakers via audio jack, music sounds great.
It has Bluetooth, and I can connect it with my phone, laptop, etc

What I want to achieve is that Ubuntu is detected as a Bluetooth speaker, so when I establish connection with my phone for example, all audio is played in there.

Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

Comment: At least on my laptop and desktop, as soon as I hook up my phone to Bluetooth it automatically broadcasts the audio over the signal.

Comment: That happens when I connect the phone to my car Bluetooth for example, but now when I connect it to Ubuntu